# Magento 2 remote validation, how to show loader

Tags: magento2, ajax, validation, loader

How to add showLoader option in this call?

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true, 'remote':'<?= $emailValidatorUrl ?>'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, it should be like that

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true, 'remote':{'url': '<?= $emailValidatorUrl ?>', 'showLoader': 'true'}}"
```